# LED Diode Circuit with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, led, diodes

I am having a hard time understanding the functions of R1 and R2 in this circuit below. Also, when the finger is touching the circuit (short circuit), would it turn on the LED or not?

I tried simulating it with LTSpice, and it seems like the LED would be always off no matter what, so I was confused with the result (Most likely that I set up the simulation wrongly).

Thank you so much for your help.

[image: MOSFET LED Circuit]

Comment: How did you model the finger in LTspice?

Comment: When the figure is not there, I just left it as open circuit and short circuit, otherwise. I ran two different simulations with two different circuit configurations essentially.

Comment: A real-world finger is not a short circuit. Usually, when someone means "manually shorting two nodes", they would draw a switch, not a finger.

Comment: Oh, I see. What would adding a finger do to the circuit?

Comment: @RoyHwang `LED Diode` is `light emitting diode diode`

Comment: FWIW, a finger typically has resistance in ballpark 100kohm (wide contact pad, strong pressure) to some megs (light pressure, dry contact); and even lower (10s of k or less) when moistened, sweaty. BS170, or 3V supply, probably isn't a great pick for this. Whether it will affect the simulation, depends on the exact values of the model in the simulation.

Comment: May I suggest ramping Vdd from, say, 1V up to 10V dc with finger out (open circuit), and observing the current in the LED.  In other words, plot LED current against Vdd.  See what you get.